# Awk: Counting fields with a pattern for each line

Tags: bash, unix, awk

This one gave me a good ol' headache just from the cheeky nature of it.

I have a file (named "votes") with about 15 lines. For each line, the first field has the name of a candidate and the next 15 fields have the 15 votes like this:

```
McBoatface y y n y n y y y n n n y n y
McDoodle n n n n n n n n n n n n n n n
Putin y n y n y y n n n n n n n y y
TheLegend27 y y y y y y y y y y y y y y y
```

y is for yes, n is for no

I wrote an awk script that counts the number of "y" for each candidate and prints it with the name of him/her:

```
McBoatface 8
McDoodle 0
Putin 6
TheLegend27 15
```

This is my try-out:

```
{
        count=0;

        for(i=$2; i<NF; i++)
        {
             if ($i == "y") count++;
        }
        printf("%s %d \n" $1, count);
}
```

But this only prints zeros after the names:

```
McBoatface 0
McDoodle 0
Putin 0
TheLegend27 0
```

What's going on? Is the `i<NF` expression wrong?

Comment: You want `for(i=2; ...` instead of `for(i=$2; ...`  What's going on is that `$2`, which may be either "y" or "n" is in neither case less than `NF`, so you never get into your for loop. And you'll also want `i<=NF` instead of `<` to make sure you reach the last of the votes.

Comment: @jas It works, but for some lines that have 7 "y"s, it prints "6"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `for(i=2; ...` instead of `for(i=$2; ...` What's going on is that $2, which may be either "y" or "n" is in neither case less than NF, so you never get into your for loop.

And you'll also want `i<=NF` instead of `<` to make sure you reach the last of the votes.

```
$ cat votes.awk
{
    count=0;
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
      if ($i == "y") count++;
    }
    print $1, count
}

$ awk -f votes.awk votes.txt 
McBoatface 8
McDoodle 0
Putin 6
TheLegend27 15
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to count the `y`s after the name (`$1`), like this:

```
$ awk '{ i=$1; $1=""; print i, gsub(/y/,"") }' file
McBoatface 8
McDoodle 0
Putin 6
TheLegend27 15
```

Explained:

```
{
    i=$1;                  # place name to var i
    $1="";                 # empty name field
    print i, gsub(/y/,"")  # print name and count of all y's
}
```